# Re-dock two QToolbars back in the same QToolbarArea

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbar

I'm working on a Qt project, where I need to get the toolbar positions at run-time. I used `QMainWindow::toolBarArea(QToolBar *toolbar)` to get the current docked area of the toolbar. And then I can use that later with `QMainWindow::addToolBar ( Qt::ToolBarArea area, QToolBar * toolbar )`.

Let's assume I dock two toolbars in a single area (i.e. Bottom area), as below.

```
-----------------------------------
| Toolbar 1                       |
-----------------------------------
| Toolbar 2                       |
-----------------------------------
```

Then I save the area obtained from `QMainWindow::toolBarArea`, using `QSettings` and then load them back with `QMainWindow::addToolBar` , it loads as below.

```
-----------------------------------
| Toolbar 1      | Toolbar 2      |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there any way to re-dock them the original form, without using `QMainWindow::saveState()`?